# Create Site using .wsp-Template

Tags: site-template, solution-package

this question may seem odd, but i can't get my head around it.

I have an .wsp Template Site Package which i want to use on a new Site. Unfortunately, i can't find this package though i added it to the Solution-Gallery on my SP..

At which point i'm doing sth. wrong?

I'm under the impression that if you added your extracted .wsp Template Solution to the Solution Gallery it should appear as a new Template if you're trying to create a new site..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was an template from a english sharepoint installation which doesn't work with german installations.. - at least i was told so.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that this is a SharePoint 2010 system:

1) I know this sounds silly, but have you put it in the correct site collection (I've seen that mistake before!)

2) Did you then **Activate** the solution in the solution gallery? Did it activate successfully?

If so, then yes, it should appear. I would then try checking the logs.

Comment: Yeah it is a SP2010, the Solution is also activated.. Where can i look at the logs?

Comment: They're usually in 14/Logs, unless you've configured them to be elsewhere.